# While deleting : ValueError: "<User: Test USER (testuser)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty sure people will say this question already has answers but I couldn't find any. In other questions, the problem appears when creating objects with many-to-many relations.

**In my case, it happens when I try to delete a record...** Eh ?!

I have the User model and the Group (`from django.contrib.auth.models import Group`) with a standard many-to-many relation between them (django standard).

Everything was working fine until I use the `depth` Meta attribute in the serializers (which is very convenient by the way !).

> My User serializer :

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models.base_user import User


class BaseUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'is_active',
            'groups',
        )
```

> My Group serializer :

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from rest_framework import serializers


class BaseGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'user_set',
        )
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        # By using the 'depth' Meta attribute, the nested User records were serialized
        # with their password. By doing this, we remove the 'password' field from the
        # representation of the Groups and their nested Users.
        for user in response.get("user_set"):
            user.pop("password", None)
        return response
```

> My API function view :

```py
@api_view(http_method_names=["DELETE"])
def user_delete(request, id):
    """
    Delete the User that corresponds to 'id'.
    """
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    user.delete()
    serializer = BaseUserSerializer(user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

> The error :

```
Internal Server Error: /api/users/45/delete/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Documents\Projects\my-project\my-project\backend\base\viewsets\base_user_viewset.py", line 142, in user_delete
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 548, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 502, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 457, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 97, in get_attribute
    instance = getattr(instance, attr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 536, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 853, in __init__
    (instance, self.pk_field_names[self.source_field_name]))
ValueError: "<User: Test USER (testuser)>" needs to have a value for field 
"id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
[27/Jan/2021 15:59:58] "DELETE /api/users/45/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 500 133778
```

If I remove the `depth = 1` from the `BaseUserSerializer`, there isn't any error.
I can't understand why it happens, and how to fix it.

*Note: The User is still effectively deleted but since there is the ValueError instead of a normal response, my frontend doesn't act as expected...*

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would avoid having the `DELETE` request path return the user details. Instead it could return the id, or success/failure based on the status of the HTTP response. However, if you want to make what you have work, you need to generate the response before deleting the user, otherwise all of those relationships are destroyed which leads to the error you're experiencing.

```
@api_view(http_method_names=["DELETE"])
def user_delete(request, id):
    """
    Delete the User that corresponds to 'id'.
    """
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    # Generate the response before deleting the user and it's relationships.
    response = Response(BaseUserSerializer(user).data)
    user.delete()
    return response
```

Additionally, you can remove the hack in BaseGroupSerializer.to_representation by using the following code. This will tell DRF which serializer to use specifically and thus constraint the fields available to those that are in BaseUserSerializer. I would actually advise against using `depth` because as you add models to your DB, they are automatically being added to your API. My instinct is to have the API only change by explicit changes.

```
class BaseGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_set = BaseUserSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'user_set',
        )
```

Comment: Indeed that works, thanks a lot ! Well I didn't think about preparing the response before deleting ahah...!    Yeah I did this to be able to say things like `User 'blabla' successfully deleted` but it is silly from me since I already have the user in the frontend... I will change that.

Comment: Concerning the `to_representation()` I initially did this when I introduced the use of `depth`. And since, before that, I faced circular imports in both of my serializers (if I wanted to serialize nested groups/users in both of them), that was, to me, the only option. But indeed I could clean it by : remove the `to_representation()` and add the call to the `BaseUserSerializer` for the `user_set`. Thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: I will follow your suggestions and avoid returning the deleted record too. So finally I shouldn't face the issue anymore just by returning something else than the serialized deleted user.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, best of luck!